# Creating a multi NIC VM in azure using ARM with my own custom template

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I am trying to find out a powershell script using ARM to create an azure VM with my own custom template, also I want my VM to be multi-nic. I was going through some blogs but I couldn't find out a way to use my own template. 
[LINK -](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud_solution_architect/archive/2015/05/05/creating-azure-vms-with-arm-powershell-cmdlets.aspx)

Also, I couldn't find a way out how multi-nic VMs can be created using ARM.

Please share your suggestions or link how this can be done.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure [Quickstart Template gallery](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) has many samples for creating multi nics - if you have your own template edit it and add those changes.
If you are looking for powershell commands, here's a good [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-network-deploy-multinic-arm-ps/)

Answer (score 1):

Multi-Nic VM must be created using Azure Power Shell Scripts.  Also creating a VM from a custom VM image with multiple nics are not supported in Azure.  The VM image must be one from the gallery in order to assign multiple nics.

What you can do is attach the VHD from your custom to a new VM image from the gallery which when creating the new VM be sure to assign the other NICs as part of the create process because once the VM is deployed without more the 1 Nic assigned you will not be able to attach the NIC to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

hi there: take a look here https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-1-vm-loadbalancer-2-nics ... this will get you started normally

Comment: It doesn't answer my own template/image usage requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look in my post on how to build one or many VMs with one or multiple NICs. Basically you have to create an object with the VMs and NICs and use the copy function to loop through them. In addition, you will need some conditional statements to ensure the resource is only created (a second NIC for instance) if the object passed has a second NIC. If you know before hand the number of NICs you will need then the conditional statement becomes unnecessary.

https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:linkedInArticle:6407154505682690048/

or

http://fbinotto.blogspot.com/2018/05/azure-arm-templates-with-conditional.html

Comment: OK I have edit it